# Unit test angular case switch formControl

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I am trying to test some function with unit test, something like this

```
  public setFormControlsValue(formControl: AbstractControl, buildingType: buildingTypeOption, value?: string): void {
    switch (buildingType) {
      case buildingTypeOption.twoToFourFacades:
      case buildingTypeOption.additionalConstruction:
      case buildingTypeOption.industrialBuilding:
        formControl.setValidators([Validators.required]);
        formControl.updateValueAndValidity();
        formControl.enable({ onlySelf: true });
        break;
      case buildingTypeOption.lightConstruction:
        debugger
        formControl.setValidators(null);
        formControl.setValue(null);
        formControl.clearValidators();
        formControl.updateValueAndValidity();
        formControl.disable({ onlySelf: true });
        break;
      case null:
        formControl.setValidators([Validators.required]);
        formControl.setValue(null);
        formControl.updateValueAndValidity();
        formControl.enable({ onlySelf: true });
        break;
      default:
        formControl.setValue(value);
        formControl.updateValueAndValidity();
        formControl.disable({ onlySelf: true });
        break;
    }
  }
```

And in unit test something like this

```
describe('has called setFormControlsValue ', () => {
    let formControlsValue = {};
    let formBuilder = new FormBuilder();
    let formControls: AbstractControl;

    beforeEach(() => {
      formControlsValue = {
        destinationEquipment: destinationEquipment.nonEquippedDestination
      };
      formControls = formBuilder.group(formControlsValue);
    });
    it('formControls should be twoToFourFacades and enabled', () => {
      // GIVEN
      // WHEN
      service.setFormControlsValue(formControls, buildingTypeOption.twoToFourFacades);
      // THEN
      expect(formControls.disabled).toBeFalsy();
    });
  });
```

Problem I have is how to test this line of code  **formControl.setValidators([Validators.required]);** or maybe I am not going in correct direction of setting test?

Answer (score 0):

> how to test this line of code
> formControl.setValidators([Validators.required]);

In prepared conditions, make relevant code execute and then, check if formControl is invalid and has proper `{required:true}` error.

```
expectThat(formControl.invalid).toBeTrue();
expectThat(formControl.errors).toEqual({required:true});
```